# Proper type for services in fetchMachine (xstate, typescript)

Tags: typescript, state-machine, xstate

I started playing with xstate and decided to start with making a fetch machine that will be responsible for every request I make to the server.

I created a simple state machine:

```
import { createMachine, assign } from "xstate";

interface FetchContext {
  readonly results: any | null;
  readonly error: null | string;
}

type FetchServices = {
  readonly fetchData: {
    readonly data: any;
  };
}

export const fetchMachine = createMachine(
  {
    context: {
      results: null,
      error: null,
    },
    tsTypes: {} as import("./fetch.typegen").Typegen0,
    schema: {
      context: {} as FetchContext,
      services: {} as FetchServices,
    },
    id: "fetch",
    initial: "idle",
    states: {
      idle: {
        on: {
          FETCH: {
            target: "pending",
          },
        },
      },
      pending: {
        invoke: {
          src: "fetchData",
          onDone: { target: "success", actions: "setResults" },
          onError: { target: "failed", actions: "setError" },
        },
      },
      success: {
        on: {
          FETCH: {
            target: "pending",
          },
        },
      },
      failed: {
        on: {
          FETCH: {
            target: "pending",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    actions: {
      setResults: assign((context, event) => {
        return {
          results: event.data,
          error: null,
        };
      }),
      setError: assign((context, event) => {
        return {
          results: null,
          error: event.data as string,
        };
      }),
    },
  }
);
```

**The main problem here is that** I want this fetchMachine to be responsible for different requests with different return types. As you can see fetched data type in my code is "any" and I want to fix that. If I used the fetchMachine just for one request, I would describe returned object type and the problem would be gone, but in my case I want this fetchMachine to be reused for many different services.

**The second problem** (not related to services) is that if I remove "as string" from "setError" action's returned propery "error", typescript complains that "event.data" is unknown type and can not be assigned to "string | null" as I described error type in FetchContext interface. Is there a way to properly type errors in this case?

Also, is it a good practice to have a single fetching machine for every "get" request in state machines? I mean, sometimes I used to create a useFetch hook to handle most of the requests, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the main problem, I would go with factory function that accepts a generic:

```js
export const createFetchMachine = <T>() =>
  createMachine(
    {
      context: {
        results: null,
        error: null,
      },
      tsTypes: {} as import("./test.typegen").Typegen0,
      schema: {
        context: {} as {
          results: T | null;
          error: null | string;
        },
        services: {} as {
          fetchData: {
            data: T;
          };
        },
      },
      id: "fetch",
```

About the second problem, you can read more about [here](https://github.com/statelyai/xstate/issues/3037). When using `typegen`, you should cast your error type as you did in your example.

As to the generic fetch machine, that was the first thing I did when I started using xState, but with time I found out that simple `invoke promises` worked better and cleaner for me.